# How to play gif image for long time or continuosly

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, timertask

How to play gif image continuously on canvas. I am using surface view. When app getting loaded that gif image is running only once and then stops automatically. Any ideas to run gif continuously.

Comment: in my knowledge .gif format not supported (functionality wise) on android but show you picture only.

Comment: Is this any help - http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gif  splitter](http://www.xoyosoft.com/gs/) and then you can use [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html). You can also set the duration of animation or play it continuously.